# How to Skip Print Specific Sheets in Workbook , IF specific cell value (D4) is blank. Vba Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to Print Some Sheets by using array code.
How to Skip Print Specific Sheet on this group, IF Cell Value (D4) is blank in any of these sheets.

```
Sub Print_Some_Sheet()

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).PrintOut , collate:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a loop for that, either to print (or not print) each sheet individually or to refine the array to exclude sheets where D4 is blank.

Here's some code that has both options, remove the one you don't want to use.

```vb
Sub Print_Some_Sheet()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim strName As Worksheet
Dim arrSheets As Variant
Dim arrSheetsToPrint As Variant
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idx As Long

    arrSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

    ReDim arrSheetsToPrint(LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets))
    
    ' option 1
    For idx = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        Set sh = Sheets(arrSheets(idx))
        If sh.Range("D4").Value <> "" Then
            sh.PrintOut , collate:=True
        End If
    Next idx
    
    ' option 2
    For idx = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        Set sh = Sheets(arrSheets(idx))
        If sh.Range("D4").Value <> "" Then
            arrSheetsToPrint(cnt) = arrSheets(idx)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next idx
    
    If cnt > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrSheetsToPrint(cnt - 1)
        Worksheets(arrSheetsToPrint).PrintOut , collate:=True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It works . Both options works.
Many thanks for your help .